# VBA unable to set range without selecting sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting a range which I've called `SCT_table` which would cover the table on worksheet one called `SCT_ws`, if this is not the active worksheet I get the error `Run-time error '1004'` and the `Set SCT_table` line is highlighted when I press debug. Now if I select this worksheet before setting the range (forcing it to be the active worksheet) it runs without a problem. Below is the code:

```
Sub Join_Suitable_changes()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim SCT_ws As Worksheet
Dim SCT_num_rows, SCT_num_cols, score_col As Long
Dim SCT_table As Range

Set SCT_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 

score_col = 7 

SCT_num_rows = SCT_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
SCT_num_cols = SCT_ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'SCT_ws.Select 'Works with this uncommented

Set SCT_table = SCT_ws.Range("A1", Cells(SCT_num_rows, SCT_num_cols))
'This causes a problem

SCT_table.Sort Key1:=Cells(1, score_col), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
'Sorts the table on column 7

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I tried this question [Cannot set a range variable without selecting sheet first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861557/cannot-set-a-range-variable-without-selecting-sheet-first) which suggested using with, and when I changed the Set part of my code to the following:

```
With SCT_ws
    Set SCT_table = .Range("A1", .Cells(SCT_num_rows, SCT_num_cols))
End With
```

I no longer need to select the WS in order to set the range (yay), however, I still need to select the WS in order for the `Sort` to work. So unfortunately this has not stopped the use of Select.

I'd appreciate any explanation as to why this is the case and how I can avoid the use of Select.

Comment: Do this.... `Set SCT_table = SCT_ws.Range("A1", SCT_ws.Cells(SCT_num_rows, SCT_num_cols))` This has been covered many times in the past. You need to fully qualify the range

Comment: You can do either what @SiddharthRout said or add the sorting inside the `With SCT_ws` and then full qualify the range with a `.` in fron of `Cells...`

Comment: The actual explanation is that if you use cells without explicitly specifying a sheet then VBA assumes you are referring to the activesheet. in the case of your sort, this means you are trying to sort cells on one sheet with a key defined on another

Comment: Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why) such question. If you search Google for `fully qualify your cells site:stackoverflow.com`, you will get many more links

Comment: @SiddharthRout If you make your answer a comment I'll accept, though I also needed to do the same for the Sort part of the code `SCT_table.Sort Key1:=SCT_ws.Cells(1, score_col), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes` Also thanks for the link to the question, I wasn't sure what the problem was so I didn't know what to search. Thanks @Harassed Dad for the explanation also.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post an answer to this question as it would not be the right thing to do in my opinion... I will close it as a duplicate though...